# Truck status by 15 minute intervals aka status changes aka utilisation

Tags: sql, timestamp, ssms, status

Please help!

Trying to get an accurate picture, by 15 minute interval, of the status of all our trucks.
I can do the status changes that occurred each 15 minute interval, but a little stumped when it comes to counting what they were in a previous interval, if they've made no changes for a few hours, and replicating that until they make another change. there's 142 trucks, so ideally I'll get 142 rows per 15 minute interval

any pointers/solutions would be hugely appreciated.

I'm guessing the query needs to look back and find previous status change then populate every 15 minute interval with that one, until the next one.

```
SELECT top 1000
RM.RESOURCE_CALLSIGN
,RM.MESSAGE_DATE
,DATEADD(MINUTE, ROUND(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, MESSAGE_DATE) / 15.0, 0) * 15, 0) [Interval]
,[MESSAGE]
,RM.STATUS_WAS
,RM.STATUS_BECAME
FROM [MOBILISATIONS].[dbo].[RESOURCE_MESSAGE] RM
where RESOURCE_CALLSIGN like '_____' and MESSAGE like '%status change%'
```

this is the piece of code I found to make a table with every 15 minute interval since a given date:

```
declare @timetbl table(t datetime)
declare @t datetime
set @t = '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
while @t <= getdate()
begin
insert into @timetbl values (@t)
set @t = dateadd(mi, 15, @t)
end
select * from @timetbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first record in each interval by doing:

```
SELECT RM.*
FROM (SELECT RM.*,
             DATEADD(MINUTE, ROUND(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, MESSAGE_DATE) / 15.0, 0) * 15, 0) as [Interval],
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(MINUTE, ROUND(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, MESSAGE_DATE) / 15.0, 0) * 15, 0)
                                ORDER BY MESSAGE_DATE) as seqnum
      FROM [STATUSCHANGES].[dbo].[RESOURCE_MESSAGE] RM
      WHERE RESOURCE_CALLSIGN like '_____' and MESSAGE like '%status change%'
     ) RM
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Then, you can get the previous value using `LAG()`:

```
SELECT RM.*,
       (CASE WHEN LAG(MESSAGE_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY MESSAGE_DATE) < DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, MESSAGE_DATE)
             THEN STATUS
             ELSE LAG(STATUS) OVER (ORDER BY MESSAGE_DATE)
        END) as prev_status
FROM (SELECT RM.*,
             DATEADD(MINUTE, ROUND(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, MESSAGE_DATE) / 15.0, 0) * 15, 0) as [Interval],
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(MINUTE, ROUND(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, MESSAGE_DATE) / 15.0, 0) * 15, 0)
                                ORDER BY MESSAGE_DATE) as seqnum
      FROM [STATUSCHANGES].[dbo].[RESOURCE_MESSAGE] RM
      WHERE RESOURCE_CALLSIGN like '_____' and MESSAGE like '%status change%'
     ) RM
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This does not fill in the missing data, but it does get the previous status (which appears to be the gist of your question).

Comment: This is great, really appreciate it. how do you take it to the next level and get 142 truck statuses per interval? i.e. if a truck goes status 3 at 1pm, it should remain status 3 for as many intervals as it takes until it goes status 4.

Comment: @ApolloGerolymbos . . . Your question seems very broad.  It is unclear which part is the real issue.  This answer addresses what I thought was the main issue.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. A combination of your earlier help and google and I've cracked it. I now have every truck's status by 15 minute interval even when they've not made a change i.e. the query looks back and finds the previous change. If you'd like the code please let me know but it is too long for this comment!

Comment: @ApolloGerolymbos . . . You can always answer your own question or add the answer back into the question itself.